# MySql conversation order by created datetime desc very slow?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am working on the chat conversation optimizations and `order by message_creation_time` is taking so long. Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    @id_max:= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM support_messages WHERE channel_id = sck.channel_id AND STATUS = 1 ) AS unique_max_id,
        sck.id,
        sck.from,
        sck.to,
        sck.channel,
        sck.channel_id,
        sck.role_type,
        sck.is_closed,
        sck.closed_at,
        sck.closed_by,
        (SELECT has_attachment FROM support_messages WHERE id = unique_max_id LIMIT 1) AS has_attachment,
        (SELECT message FROM support_messages WHERE id = unique_max_id LIMIT 1) AS last_message,
        (SELECT created_at FROM support_messages WHERE id = unique_max_id LIMIT 1) AS message_creation_time,
        (SELECT is_pinned FROM assign_support_conversations WHERE channel_id = sck.channel_id LIMIT 1) AS is_pinned,
        (SELECT id FROM assign_support_conversations WHERE channel_id = sck.channel_id LIMIT 1) AS assign_support_id,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM support_messages WHERE uid_to = 3 AND channel_id = sck.channel_id AND seen IN (0,1)) AS unread_messages,
        (CASE WHEN (sck.from = 3) 
                    THEN (SELECT username  FROM `user` WHERE id = sck.to LIMIT 1) 
                    ELSE (SELECT username FROM `user` WHERE id = sck.from LIMIT 1)  
                    END) AS to_username
        FROM support_contacts_keys AS sck
         LEFT JOIN `assign_support_conversations` AS `asc` ON asc.channel_id = sck.channel_id 
        WHERE sck.role_type = 'support'  AND asc.is_pinned IN (0, 1)     AND is_closed = 0
        GROUP BY sck.channel_id
        HAVING unread_messages >= 0 
        ORDER BY message_creation_time DESC 
        LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I also try to explain the query.

> Note: When I remove this "ORDER BY message_creation_time DESC " it takes 0.09 seconds and if include this order by clause it takes 3.571 Seconds.

Here is the explanation of this query

[image]

**support_contacts_keys**

```
CREATE TABLE `support_contacts_keys` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_type` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_closed` tinyint(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `closed_at` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx-support_contacts_keys-from` (`from`),
   KEY `idx-support_contacts_keys-to` (`to`),
   KEY `idx-support_contacts_keys-channel_id` (`channel_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk-support_contacts_keys-from` FOREIGN KEY (`from`) 
   REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `fk-support_contacts_keys-to` FOREIGN KEY (`to`) 
   REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55808 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 
   COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

**support_messages**

```
CREATE TABLE `support_messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `app_msg_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_attachment` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT 1,
  `message_sent_by` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_downtime_message` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `has_gathern_url` tinyint(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_unix` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx-support_messages-uid_from` (`uid_from`),
  KEY `idx-support_messages-uid_to` (`uid_to`),
  KEY `idx-support_messages-channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  KEY `support_messages_status_idx` (`status`),
  KEY `support_messages_channel_id_and_status_and_created_unix_idx` 
  (`channel_id`,`status`,`created_unix`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk-support_messages-uid_from` FOREIGN KEY (`uid_from`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk-support_messages-uid_to` FOREIGN KEY (`uid_to`) 
  REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=426372 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 
  COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what indexes you have.

Comment: ok, let me edit the question.